# How to disable the Login Button in MS Indentity Login.cshtml page when submitting the user id & password

Tags: c#, blazor, identity, server-side

I have created a Blazor Server side website, with Identity authentication. I have scaffolded the Login.cshtml page.

I want to disable the login button during the login process. I cannot figure out how to disable the Login button after it has been clicked and *only* if the user id and password fields has passed the validation process :-(

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditForm Model="ViewModel" OnSubmit="@HandleLogin">

<div>
     <button @onclick="HandleSaveFiles" type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" disabled="@(!LoginCompleted)">Login</button>
</div>

 </EditForm>

@code {

    public bool LoginCompleted { get; set; } = true;
    
    protected async Task HanleLogin()
    {
       
        LoginCompleted = false;

      //your login process....
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'Login.cshtml' is a ASP MVC page. As far as I know, I cannot enter Razor syntax in such a page?

Comment: i thought you use razor component :(
you have to use js to active or disable login button
why don't you use razor componrnt ?